# I am getting an error: External table is not in a valid format. Trying to open .xlsx file on server

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I am getting an error: External table is not in a valid format., whenever I try to open .xlsx(which is shared on server with full permission given to all users) file through my C# project. It works perfectly fine whenever I run it on my pc. But if I try it on a client PC it gives the above error!
The connection string I am using is:

```
cn = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source= \\Michael\Ecxel Prac2\Book1.xlsx;extended properties=excel 12.0;");
```

I tried looking it up, but none of the suggested solutions worked!!
my PC specs are: windows7 64bit 
client PC specs are: windows7 32/64 bit

P.S. I am running it on x86 since it doesn't work on 'x64' or 'Any CPU'

Comment: There is not Excel provider for x64. I think your problem is related to opening the file from the remote location. Have you tried coping it locally to a temp folder before processing?

Comment: no I haven't as the excel file works as my database. Yes, I do know that there is no Excel provider for x64!

Comment: oh yeah..it seems that whenever I keep the excel file open on my client PC and then run the program it works fine!! I don't want to keep doing that to run it fine!!

Comment: @Oscar: hey I think i found out what the problem is, my client went a head and tried using macro in the excel. So is there a way I could still use the excel file?? (macro enabled!)

Comment: Do you have calculated columns in the file? If not, you could try coping&pasting the data to a new fiel without macros.. 
Also, see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825155/enable-excel-macro-in-codes